# streamlit pyplot subplot distortion

Tags: python, matplotlib, streamlit

I'm plotting images with subplot and it looks different in Jupyter (or "pure python") vs. Streamlit.

For example, if I have a **(2 x 2)** subplot with just **1 image**, it will be **stretched** in Streamlit.

How I can **turn off** such stretching?

##### Plots without Streamlit:

[image]

##### Plots in Streamlit

[image: streamlit plot]

##### Code:

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imgs = [np.random.random((50,50)) for _ in range(4)]

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1);
plt.imshow(imgs[0]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2);
plt.imshow(imgs[1]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3);
plt.imshow(imgs[2]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4);
plt.imshow(imgs[3]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.025, hspace=.025)
st.pyplot(fig1)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1);
plt.imshow(imgs[0]);
plt.axis('off');
st.pyplot(fig2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may save the image by using plt.savefig(...) and then present the image with st.image, for a higher resolution you can insert the dpi parameter.

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

imgs = [np.random.random((50,50)) for _ in range(4)]

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1);
plt.imshow(imgs[0]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2);
plt.imshow(imgs[1]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3);
plt.imshow(imgs[2]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4);
plt.imshow(imgs[3]);
plt.axis('off');
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.025, hspace=.025)


# save image, display it, and delete after usage.
plt.savefig('x',dpi=400)
st.image('x.png')
os.remove('x.png')

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1);
plt.imshow(imgs[0]);
plt.axis('off');

# save second image, display it, and delete after usage.
plt.savefig('test',dpi=400)
st.image('test.png')
os.remove('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant workaround!

Comment: the word for this, I would say is 'brilliant'!